# Twitter API Python script "not authorized" after a while

Tags: python, twitter, amazon-web-services, unauthorized

I have a Python 3.3 script that calls the Twitter API function **/followers/ids**. (I use this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter)

Because of the Twitter rate limits, the scripts takes many days to run (15 calls then 15 minutes pause,...).

In my local tests the script works fine but when I let it run on an Amazon AWS small instance, after half a day or so twitter always starts returning "status 401: not authorized". What could be the reason for this? I have no idea what could cause the different behaviour on my local machine and on the amazon server? I also don't get any other errors from Python.

EDIT: Actually there is no difference between my PC and the Amazon server. It noticed that it happens on both.

Answer (score 0):

The `401: Not Authorized` message most likely means that despite your efforts to stay within the rate limits, Twitter is preventing your AWS instance access to their API now. The different in behavior is likely due to the different source IP - your local connection vs. and Amazon AWS IP.

Comment: Actually it happens locally too now. The script runs for about half a day (15 requests -> 15 minutes pause,...) and then Twitter starts returning the 401 status. If I restart the script it works again. Isn't that strange?

I would need that the script can run a least for a month or so. Could it be that they don't like my account anymore? :) During my experiments I run into the rate limits a lot. But the current script adheres the limits and doesn't run into them.

Answer (score 0):

The `401: Not Authorized` message usually means that the target account of the `/followers/ids` call is a protected one. In more detail, the account's owner has set up his account to only allow his followers access the complete profile info. For more info check the [public and protected tweets](https://support.twitter.com/articles/14016)  and [profile visibility settings](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20172733) of the official Twitter documentation.